# How cast or convert array value string to boolean in php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Working with Laravel `ACL`.In every Role have group of permissions. I represent the all permissions using checkbox. When I submit form it's return a permissions array like this.

```
{
read: "true",
create: "true",
delete: "false",
update: "false"
}
```

array value show as `double quotes` string ,but i want it as `boolean` 
How can i cast array values string to boolean.

```
@foreach($role->permissions as $key=>$value)

           <td>
           <input type="hidden" name="permission[{{$key}}]" class="role" value="false" {{ $value==0 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
           <input type="checkbox" name="permission[{{$key}}]" class="role" value="true" {{ $value==1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
            </td>
@endforeach
```

I want to array value like this.

```
{
read: true,
create: true,
delete: false,
update: false
}
```

Comment: in your case cast $value as (boolean)$value

Comment: inside foreach loop or where ?

Comment: inside foreach loop

Comment: `@foreach($role->permissions as $key=>(boolean)$value)` i'm try this way it's show **unexpected '(bool)' (bool) (T_BOOL_CAST)** error

Comment: where ever you use $value cast there, not in foreach statement,see my answer

Answer (score 0):

HTML double quotes values. If your values are always going to be "true" or "false" then you can specifically check for "true".

```
// change your json into an array
$values = json_decode($yourValues, true) ;

// loop through and check for "true"
foreach($values as $key=>$value) {
    $values[$key] = ($value == "true") ;
}

// if you need it as json again
$yourValues = json_encode($values) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

For you case,

```
@foreach($role->permissions as $key=>$value)
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="permission[{{$key}}]" class="role" value="false" {{ (boolean)$value ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permission[{{$key}}]" class="role" value="true" {{ (boolean)$value? 'checked' : '' }}>
     </td>
@endforeach
```

Try like this

**####edit####**

```
$data=$_POST[];
foreach($data as $record){
    $record=(boolean)$record;
   //now $record is boolean 
}
```

Comment: still now show `{
read: "true",
create: "true",
delete: "false",
update: "false"
}`

Comment: sorry, I got it now. Is this data after submitting form right? then you should use casting where you use that result, by form submitting you always get string values only, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
@foreach($role->permissions as $key=>$value)

           <td>
           <input type="hidden" name="permission[{{$key}}]" class="role" value=false {{ $value=='false' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
           <input type="checkbox" name="permission[{{$key}}]" class="role" value=true {{ $value=='true' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
            </td>
@endforeach
```